# DateTime.TryParse issue, may relate to Globalization Setting in IIS

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, globalization

Basically,I am reading excel file where one of that columns has date format like : `dd/MM/yyyy` eg: `11/04/2016`

When I am using `DateTime.TryParse()` to parse that string into datetime method `TryParse()` treated first numbers like month (number 11 in example above). However the same code running on the other computers will take the second number (04 in example above) as the month.

So my question is why there is a difference between them, what actually decide the behavior of `TryParse` method?

Comment: [`TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.110).aspx): "If a specific date and time format will be parsed across different locales, use the DateTime.TryParse(String, IFormatProvider, DateTimeStyles, DateTime) method or one of the overloads of the TryParseExact method and provide a format specifier."

Comment: Yes, I know specifying a format can solve this problem, but just want to know what exactly accounts the difference there???

Answer (score 0):

I think the main difference is in IFormatProvider (hard to say if I can't check some settings in target system), but I usually use other method to get proper DateTime object:

```
DateTime someDate = DateTime.ParseExact(myStringDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

It always gives me what I want no matter how client environment is configured.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: This format does not match with OP's format. And `Globalization` does not have a property or field called `InvariantCulture` since it is a namespace. It should be like `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` at least.

Comment: edited and corrected, but my format is only a simple sample. i think anyone knows how to replace it, but to be fair to Your comment: `DateTime someDate = DateTime.ParseExact(myStringDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Answer (score -1):

From [`DateTime.TryParse(String, DateTime)` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Because the `DateTime.TryParse(String, DateTime)` method tries to parse
>   the string representation of a date and time using the formatting
>   rules of the current culture, **trying to parse a particular string
>   across different cultures can either fail or return different results**.
>   If a specific date and time format will be parsed across different
>   locales, use the
>   `DateTime.TryParse(String, IFormatProvider, DateTimeStyles, DateTime)`
>   method or one of the overloads of the `TryParseExact` method and provide
>   a format specifier.

That means your computers have different culture settings which is pointed in [`CurrentCulture` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture).

Looks like one computer's current culture have `dd/MM/yyyy` and the other computer's current culture have `MM/dd/yyyy` as a standard date and time format.

Since you are sure your values are always in `dd/MM/yyyy` format, I would use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact) instead of `Datetime.TryParse` or `DateTime.TryParseExact` methods like;

```
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(yourColumnValue, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Or you can sets all computers current culture to like the first computer but remember, [`CultureInfo` data is not a stable data](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnste/2005/04/05/culture-data-shouldnt-be-considered-stable-except-for-invariant/) that *might* be change in future with a windows update, .NET Framework version or OS version.